# how can i fetch a column without table name associated with it in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-db

i am unable to separte the table with the field from the below query. every query becomes
table_name.field_name but i want only field_name as i want to output dummy string from the sql but i am unable to achieve this

```
$select1 = $dbAdapter->select()
     ->from("list",array("list_id","xyz"));
```

the above query results generates following sql

```
SELECT `list`.`list_id`, `list`.`xyz` FROM `list`;
```

but i want my query as

```
 SELECT `list`.`list_id`, `xyz` FROM `list`;
```

how can i achieve this result...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Expression Column](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr) for this. For example

```
$select = $dbAdapter->select()
    ->from(
        "list",
        array(
            "list_id",
            new Zend_Db_Expr("xyz")
        )
    );
```

> Columns in SQL queries are sometimes expressions, not simply column
>   names from a table. Expressions should not have correlation names or
>   quoting applied.